# Big perfect rectangle from small rectangles with subjectivities

Tags: python, algorithm, excel, vba

I want to arrange rectangles which will form a big perfect rectangle with no spaces- big rectangle size known.

I prefer to do it in Excel but even python could be a good solution. - for starting idea of algorithms is also welcome.

1. Each rectangle has a size length and width ( no flipping allowed)and a Y level.
2. I know for sure that there is a solution and I know exactly the big rectangle size.
3. If I will put the big rectangle on axis, the Y axis will have few (3-10) levels for example the points (0,100) (0,250) (0,1000).
4. The bottom of each small rectangle should start on a level pre-defined (Y axis)
   So actually for each level I have the specific rectangles the I need to decide the order.

My input looks like:

- rec. number
- Width
- Hight
- starting level (Y axis)

Expected output if the big rectangle bottom left point will be on (0,0) axis:

- Rec. No.
- bottom left point where the rec. should start

Any Ideas ? I know that it is a hard problem but I have small number of rectangle ..

Thank you

Comment: This is quite unclear. You need to clarify exactly what your input and what your output is in terms of e.g. actual data structures. Also -- show some code which you have written to try to flesh out your ideas.

Comment: I need to find an algorithm first.. no code yet

Comment: Input : rec. 1, size 400x1000 , starts at 250 ( Y coordinate) .. of course the input contains the big rectangle size as well. Output: rec. 1 , (50,250) bottom left corner position. All rec. should form perfect big rec. with no spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can in numpy first initialize an empty grid and then access the different entries individually

```
grid=np.zeros(1000,1000)
for in range(phases)
grid[startx[i]:startx[i]+with,starty[i]:starty[i]+Hight[i]==rec_number[i]
```

startx is the array including the starting points in x direction
the other just follow the same principle of your input